# Problems debugging mserver5

Tags: monetdb

I have recently started debugging the `mserver5` application using `vscode` and a very comfy plugin for `cmake` called `CMake Tools`. Moreover, I am using `gcc 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)` as a compiler together with the following `launch.json` debug configuration for `mserver5` in `vscode`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) mserver5 triangleDB",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            // Resolved by CMake Tools:
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": ["--dbpath=/home/mledl/dbfarm/triangleDB", "--set", "mapi_port=0"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build",
            "environment": [
                {
                    // add the directory where our target was built to the PATHs
                    // it gets resolved by CMake Tools:
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "$PATH:${command:cmake.launchTargetDirectory}"
                },
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {   "description":"In this mode GDB will be attached to both processes after a call to fork() or vfork().",
                    "text": "-gdb-set detach-on-fork off",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {   "description": "The new process is debugged after a fork. The parent process runs unimpeded.",
                    "text": "-gdb-set follow-fork-mode child",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The database I am connecting to (here `triangleDB`) has been created within a `dbfarm` using the `monetdb` application and I am going to connect to it using the `mclient` application with the default username and password combination `monetdb`. I can successfully connect to and query my `triangleDB` when starting it using the `monetdb` application withing a running `dbfarm`.

When starting up the `mserver5` for debugging from `vscode` using the above `launch.json` file and connecting to it using `mclient` and the `monetdb` user I cannot authenticate somehow and get the following error printed to the `mserver5` logs:

```
client1: createExceptionInternal: !ERROR: InvalidCredentialsException:checkCredentials:invalid credentials for user 'monetdb'
```

Does anybody know why `mserver5` cannot retrieve the default user? Does it rely on the deamon `monetdbd` to retrieve the user data from? Can someone tell me what I am missing or how I can efficiently debug the `mserver5`?

Another point is that I need to set `mapi_port=0` in order to make `mserver5` bind to available ports since it is opening two `mapi connections` somehow when debugging with `vscode` and `CLion`. The application crashes when using a specific port since the second binding attempt will be on an already use address. The following section shows that two connections are opened when debugging:

```
# MonetDB 5 server v11.40.0
# This is an unreleased version
# Serving database 'triangleDB', using 24 threads
# Compiled for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/64bit with 128bit integers
# Found 31.349 GiB available main-memory of which we use 25.549 GiB
# Copyright (c) 1993 - July 2008 CWI.
# Copyright (c) August 2008 - 2021 MonetDB B.V., all rights reserved
# Visit https://www.monetdb.org/ for further information
# Listening for connection requests on mapi:monetdb://localhost:46093/
# Listening for connection requests on mapi:monetdb://localhost:40387/
```

Thanks in advance for everybody that can help me out on this one. Looking forward to hearing from you and sty safe everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database was created using `monetdb` and you want to start it directly using `mserver5`, you need to tell `mserver5` where the `.vaultkey` is.

In you `dbfarm`, do a `grep monet_vault_key merovingian.log`, copy the whole `--set monet_vault_key=/<path-to>/dbfarm/demo/.vaultkey` and add this option to the start-up command of your `mserver5`.

Comment: Thanks @Jenni for this helpful answer. I finally could authenticate with `mserver5`. However, I am facing another problem now, somehow the SQL scenario could not be initialized and i get the following exception: `client5: createExceptionInternal: !ERROR: MALException:setScenario:Scenario not initialized 'sql'`.

When i specify the language to use MAL using the `mclient` everything works fine. I have seen that there is just the MAL config present in `mal_scenario.c`. Do you have any suggestion on how to get this work using SQL language?

Comment: I have pinned it down a little more. The problem is, that mserver5 cannot find the library `lib_sql.so` which I assumed to be compiled during regular build of the application. I can find a bunch of libraries having the same naming convention (which are also loaded by `mserver5`) under  `/usr/local/lib/monetdb5` (for example `lib_generator.so` or `lib_opt_sql_append.so`. Do I have to set some special flag to get `lib_sql.so` compiled?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an additional answer here, because I want to make clear what I had to do in order to debug the `mserver5` using `vscode` and interact with it using the `mclient` application.

While trying to figure out why certain modules/libraries could not be loaded, I noticed that the `GDK kernel` is missing an environment variable called `monet_mod_path` which can be set using the `--set monet_mod_path=/usr/local/lib/monetdb5` option for `mserver5`. The missing `monet_mod_path` has also been the reason why `mserver5` listened on two addresses for a `mapi connection`.

I am now using the following command to start `mserver5` for debugging:

```
mserver5 --dbpath=/home/mledl/dbfarm/triangleDB --set monet_vault_key=/home/mledl/dbfarm/triangleDB/.vaultkey --set monet_mod_path=/usr/local/lib/monetdb5 --set gdk_nr_threads=24 --set max_clients=64 --set sql_optimizer=default_pipe
```

A minimal working configuration would be the following one:

```
mserver5 --dbpath=/path/to/your/db --set monet_vault_key=/path/to/your/db/.vaultkey --set monet_mod_path=/usr/local/lib/monetdb5
```

**Note**: I installed the application into default installation directory. If you choose a custom one the monet module path has the following pattern:
`monet_mod_path=/path/to/install/lib/monetdb5`

I hope this answer will help someone in the future and saves all the investigation time I had to put in.